# Using "titlepages" by Peter R. Wilson

Tags: chapters, titles

I'm trying to use the samples that are offered by Peter Wilson's package of Title Pages.

Link to document:

http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/latex-samples/TitlePages/titlepages.pdf

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlepages

This is the code I have used however it's not working and giving the following errors:

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\author{Me}

\newcommand*{\titleTMB}{\begingroup% Three Men in a Boat
\drop=0.1\txtheight
\centering
\settowidth{\unitlength}{\LARGE THE BOOK OF CONUNDRUMS}
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
{\large\scshape the author}\\[\baselineskip]
\rule{\unitlength}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt}
\rule{\unitlength}{0.4pt}\\[\baselineskip]
{\LARGE THE BOOK OF CONUNDRUMS}\\[\baselineskip]
{\itshape puzzles for the mind}\\[0.2\baselineskip]
\rule{\unitlength}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt}
\rule{\unitlength}{1.6pt}\\[\baselineskip]
{\large\scshape drawings by the artist}\par
\vfill
{\large\scshape the publisher}\\[\baselineskip]
{\small\scshape year}\par
\vspace*{\drop}
\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\titleTMB
\end{document}
```

**Errors:**

[image]

Can someone help me out figure what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

- there is a typo: `\txtheight` is missing an e
- `\newlength{\drop}` is missing (from page 45 of the linked pdf)

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\author{Me}

\newlength{\drop}% for my convenience

\newcommand*{\titleTMB}{\begingroup% Three Men in a Boat
\drop=0.1\textheight
\centering
\settowidth{\unitlength}{\LARGE THE BOOK OF CONUNDRUMS}
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
{\large\scshape the author}\\[\baselineskip]
\rule{\unitlength}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt}
\rule{\unitlength}{0.4pt}\\[\baselineskip]
{\LARGE THE BOOK OF CONUNDRUMS}\\[\baselineskip]
{\itshape puzzles for the mind}\\[0.2\baselineskip]
\rule{\unitlength}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt}
\rule{\unitlength}{1.6pt}\\[\baselineskip]
{\large\scshape drawings by the artist}\par
\vfill
{\large\scshape the publisher}\\[\baselineskip]
{\small\scshape year}\par
\vspace*{\drop}
\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\titleTMB

test

\end{document}
```